# How to use tf::poseMsgToEigen

Tags: ros, eigen, ik, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm kind of confused on how I should use tf::poseMsgToEigen. I have

```
#include <tf/tf.h>
#include <tf/transform_listener.h>
#include <eigen_conversions/eigen_msg.h>
```

and

```
tf::TransformListener *tf_listener = NULL;
tf::poseMsgToEigen(end_target, end_effector_state);
```

end_target is in geometry_msgs::Pose and end_effector_state should be in the eigen form as the documentation suggests but I keep getting error such as:

```
no matching function for call to ‘poseMsgToEigen(geometry_msgs::Pose&, const Affine3d&)’
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282172/how-to-use-tf::posemsgtoeigen/) by [JuanTelo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32449/juantelo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2018-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The key is the `const Affine3d&` in your error. It's hard to tell without a complete code snippet, but it seems like the compiler thinks that `end_effector_state` is constant, and there isn't a function call that takes a `const Affine3d&`, only one that takes an `Affine3d&`. Your solution would be to initialize a different variable that isn't `const` and use that instead.

```
Eigen::Affine3d end_effector_mutable;
tf::poseMsgToEigen(end_target, end_effector_mutable);
```

---

Originally posted by [BryceWilley](https://answers.ros.org/users/33606/brycewilley/) with karma: 711 on 2018-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2